# Delete a code-first migration before update-database was run

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

This frustratingly simple seeming question has been difficult to find an answer to on Google and SO. I have an ASP.NET MVC project that I am using Entity Framework with a code-first approach. I went to add another migration but when I ran the `Add-Migration MigrationName` command, I misspelled the `MigrationName`.

I have not yet run `Update-Database`. Would renaming the migration class name that was automatically created be enough? Or do I have to delete the migration first and add a new one with the correct name? If so, how do I do that? Just delete the automatically created migration class or is there more to it?

Comment: Just delete the class and recreate, nothing more exciting is needed. you can probably rename it, but it's good to get into the habit of auto-generating this stuff.

Comment: Great thanks @DavidG! Post this as the answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @DavidG wouldn't just deleting the class not cause the changes to be picked up in another attempted migration?  As the changes from the migration are already a part of the snapshot?  Or does this change depending on which version of EF you're using?

Comment: If you haven't run update-database yet, then nothing has changed other than a new class file in your solution.  Just delete it and run add-migration again.

Comment: @Kritner That's the point. Delete it and add another migration with the correct name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you may be able to rename them, I think you may come up with some issues with regards to the `*.resx` file that gets created as it contains a zipped up EDMX file along with some naming stuff. The simplest way is to delete the root migration class (which will also remove the `migration.Designer.cs` and `migration.resx` file) and recreate it.

If you have already ran an `Update-Database` command, you can still achieve it by rolling this back:

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration NameOfPreviousMigration
```

(you may need to add `-Force` if the rollback will destroy data)

Comment: @taha Not sure why you thought [that edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27175754) was a good idea - it would have broken this answer